# How to pass an int[] array into main(String []args)?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to write a program that begins in the main method, and calls a method that contains an integer array.

Essentially, the program is a basic lift that assumes all inputs are received at the same time. The stops the lift will make are stored in an array called stoppages which is a combination of the stops of the lift going up, and the stops of the lift going down.

I want the program to start in main, and call the method that sorts all of the floors and such. However, when I run the program it changes all of the values of the final array into 0's.

Why is it doing this, and what needs to be done to allow the array values to remain unchanged when the program is run?

This is the main method:

```
public class user_interface {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    floor_sorting.sorting_floors(args);
     }
}
```

And this is the method I'm trying to call:

```
import java.util.*;
 public class floor_sorting{

   public static void sorting_floors(int[] args){

      //bubble sort - sorts out user_up in ascending order
      for (int i = 0; i < user_stops.user_up.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < user_stops.user_up.length - i; x++) {
                   if (user_stops.user_up[x-1] > user_stops.user_up[x]){
                         int temp = user_stops.user_up[x-1];
                         user_stops.user_up[x-1] = user_stops.user_up[x];
                         user_stops.user_up[x] = temp;   
                   }
            }
      }

      //bubble sort again, but in descending order
      for (int i = 0; i < user_stops.user_down.length; i++) {
            for (int x = 1; x < user_stops.user_down.length - i; x++) {
              if (user_stops.user_down[x-1] < user_stops.user_down[x]){
                     int temp = user_stops.user_down[x-1];
                     user_stops.user_down[x-1] = user_stops.user_down[x];
                     user_stops.user_down[x] = temp;       
              }
      }
      }


      //merges the two separate arrays into one (user_up + user_down = stoppages)  
      int stoppages[] = new int[user_stops.user_up.length+user_stops.user_down.length];
      System.arraycopy(user_stops.user_up, 0, stoppages,0, user_stops.user_up.length);
      System.arraycopy(user_stops.user_down, 0, stoppages, user_stops.user_up.length, user_stops.user_down.length);

      int c = 0;

      do {
            System.out.println("The lift has come to stop at floor " + stoppages[c]);
          System.out.println("The lift has started moving again."); 
          c++;
      } while (c < stoppages.length);

      do {
            System.out.println("This lift has stopped moving forever.");
      } while (c!=stoppages.length);
   }
   }
```

The above method calls this method:

```
import java.util.*;
public class user_stops {
//user_up array declaration 
public static int user_up[] = new int [6];{

//Initialising data in array     
user_up[0] = 1;
user_up[1] = 3;

user_up[2] = 2;
user_up[3] = 7;

user_up[4] = 5;
user_up[5] = 8;
}


//user_down array declaration   
public static int user_down[] = new int [6];{

//user_down data initialisation
user_down[0] = 8;
user_down[1] = 5;

user_down[2] = 4;
user_down[3] = 2;

user_down[4] = 6;
user_down[5] = 1;

}

}
```

Comment: You have not specified your parameters in your call to sorting_floors from the main method.

Comment: You'll need to convert the array of strings into an array of ints before passing it to your `sorting_floors` method. You could just declare an `int[]` of the size of the `String[]` array, then loop over the string array and convert each value to int. That would be one way.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm relatively new to java. @SteveClaridge

Comment: @crush, I don't have any string arrays? I only have int arrays, that being the problem.

Comment: `main()` is called at runtime, and passed all parameters you specified as an array of strings: `String[] args`. You need to convert that into `int[]` and pass it to your `sorting_floors` function when you call it.

Comment: You don't use the args in `main()` at all, do you? I'm not sure why your arrays in the test data are being set to zero, but as others have noted, you will need to convert your input arguments using something like `Integer.parseInt(String s)`. I'm surprised it compiles though,

Comment: @AchimSchmitz would this be done in the main method, or the floor_sorting method?

Comment: I just tried out the code you've shown. As expected it gives a compile error in the class `user_interface`. If you ever wish to use that `main()` method, you should make the conversion there before the call to `sorting_floors()`. See Stephen C's answer below. He describes it pretty clearly. That won't help though as long as you use the class `user_stops`. You don't seem to use the input argument at all. I'm wondering why?

Comment: See my answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To force your code to run, I simply changed the call in `main()` :

```
floor_sorting.sorting_floors(new int[]{1,2,3});
```

The input array is ignored as I mentioned in my comments. However, it does print out nothing but zeros when it runs. (How did you figure that out?)

The reason is your use of static members in `user_stops`. These being static means they are not being instantiated at any point. This is not obvious unless you realise that even static members of a class will not always be instantiated.

I added the following statement at the top of `sorting_floors()`:

```
user_stops user_stops_1 = new user_stops();
```

The program now runs as expected. (Go ahead... try it.) Another thing that might have worked, though I didn't try it, is to initiate the static arrays in the declaration:

```
public static  int user_up[] = new int [] {1, 3, 2, 7, 5, 8};
public static int user_down[] = new int [] {8, 5, 4, 2, 6, 1};
```

However, I think you should **re-think** your use of the key-word `static` if you ever want this program to work properly.

Answer (score 5):

> I want the program to start in main, and call the method that sorts all of the floors and such. However, when I run the program it changes all of the values of the final array into 0's.

The code you have shown us won't even compile.  This line is invalid:

```
floor_sorting.sorting_floors;
```

We can't explain what a program does if you don't show us the real code.

---

If you want to make it compile you need to convert your array of `String` into an array of `int`.  The simple way is to:

1. allocate an `int[]` of the right size (i.e. the same size as the `String[] args` array),
2. loop over the range of the arrays, and
3. use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert the values.

Read the javadocs for the `Integer` class ...

---

Finally, you need to pay a lot more attention to style:

- Your code's indentation is a mess.
- You are violating the style rules for identifiers.  A class name should start with an uppercase letter, and should use "camel case" not underscores.

Code like the above is hard to read, and will get you endless criticism / complaints from co-workers.  (And it *should* lose you marks if this is a marked assignment.)

Comment: I must have copied the main method wrong, I had it written properly in eclipse window!
Ok, thanks for the help, I'll give it a go.

Comment: In regards to your final edit, I've had to copy & paste the code over a few times, resulting in the odd formatting. I've been focusing mainly on getting it to work before making it look pretty, but thanks for the advice! @Stephen

Comment: @BarneyGibbins - Get it working first is fine ... but NOT if you are going to ask other people to read it before it is working.

Comment: @BarneyGibbins I strongly suggest you pay attention to Stephen's points about ***attention to style***. It's extremely important. You should research Java coding standards, and try to adhere to them.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit please? All I've been told is that it's a mess, which isn't very constructive. What is a more appropriate indentation style? @crush

Comment: @BarneyGibbins You should study the [**official Java coding conventions**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) as I said. It's simply too broad of a topic to discuss in comments here. If you have questions about how to interpret that document, you could search StackOverflow for similar questions, or ask about it if you can't find a relevant search result. Furthermore, it would be a good idea to do something like review Java source code to get an idea of how Oracle formatted their own code. Likewise, you could examine source code of mature Java projects.

Comment: For starters, every compound statement (that's anything between `{}`) should be indented to a new line. The opening `{` should be on the same line to the statement to which it belongs (if it belongs to one - usually it does).

Comment: Sorry, I meant indented to a new tab or 4 spaces (not new line).